# How to copy the prior month's last observation's value to other observations?

Tags: stata, lag, price

In Stata

- Daily price data, `permno` is the company identifier
- For each `permno month`, I want price end of last month

```
tsset permno date

gen m= mofd(date)

format m %tm

* price end of each month 

bys permno m: gen prc_end= prc[_N]

* price end of the prior month

gen n=m-1

format n %tm

bys permno m: gen prc_endpm= prc_end if n==m[_n-1]

* no results
```

Current Data:

permno  date    prc m   prc_end n

10026   24-Jan-19   145.8000031 2019m1  154.35  2018m12

10026   25-Jan-19   144.5500031 2019m1  154.35  2018m12

10026   28-Jan-19   140 2019m1  154.35  2018m12

10026   29-Jan-19   156.8200073 2019m1  154.35  2018m12

10026   30-Jan-19   150.5   2019m1  154.35  2018m12

10026   31-Jan-19   154.3500061 2019m1  154.35  2018m12

10026   01-Feb-19   154.8000031 2019m2  155.28  2019m1

10026   04-Feb-19   158.4400024 2019m2  155.28  2019m1

10026   05-Feb-19   158.2599945 2019m2  155.28  2019m1

10026   06-Feb-19   158.2400055 2019m2  155.28  2019m1

10026   07-Feb-19   156.4100037 2019m2  155.28  2019m1

Comment: A minimal reproducible example is needed to make your question clearer.

Comment: I have now supplied such, but MREs are vital for good questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What you've supplied is better, but doesn't meet the standards in the `stata` tag wiki. In a nutshell: use the `dataex` command in Stata.

Comment: I have added some observations. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make things clearer, consider a silly example dataset.

```
clear 
set obs 6 
gen permno = 1 
gen date = mdy(1 + (_n > 3), real(word("1 15 31 1 15 28", _n)), 2022)
format date %td 
gen m = mofd(date)
format m %tm 
gen n = m - 1 
format n %tm 
gen price = _n 

list, sepby(permno m)

 
     +-----------------------------------------------+
     | permno        date        m         n   price |
     |-----------------------------------------------|
  1. |      1   01jan2022   2022m1   2021m12       1 |
  2. |      1   15jan2022   2022m1   2021m12       2 |
  3. |      1   31jan2022   2022m1   2021m12       3 |
     |-----------------------------------------------|
  4. |      1   01feb2022   2022m2    2022m1       4 |
  5. |      1   15feb2022   2022m2    2022m1       5 |
  6. |      1   28feb2022   2022m2    2022m1       6 |
     +-----------------------------------------------+
```

Now

```
bys permno m: gen prc_end= price[_N]
```

will probably work, but this would be safer:

```
bys permno m (date): gen prc_end= price[_N]
```

Things go wrong when you go

```
bys permno m: gen prc_endpm= prc_end if n==m[_n-1]
```

The effect of the `by:` is to confine calculations to blocks with the same `permno` and monthly date. `[_n-1]` here is legal but it refers to the previous observation **in the same block of observations** (usefully if there is one; if there isn't the code is still legal).

You want `[_n-1]` to refer to the previous month (and the same `permno`) but that is not what your syntax means. Also, the example shows that, although your syntax is legal, there are no observations that satisfy your `if` condition, as `m` and `n` are never equal within the same block of observations.

What you want can be done with `by:` but you need to look across months.

This should do it:

```
bysort permno (m date) : gen previous = price[_n-1] if m[_n-1] == m -1 
bysort permno m (date) : replace previous = previous[1]

list, sepby(permno m)

     +----------------------------------------------------------+
     | permno        date        m         n   price   previous |
     |----------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |      1   01jan2022   2022m1   2021m12       1          . |
  2. |      1   15jan2022   2022m1   2021m12       2          . |
  3. |      1   31jan2022   2022m1   2021m12       3          . |
     |----------------------------------------------------------|
  4. |      1   01feb2022   2022m2    2022m1       4          3 |
  5. |      1   15feb2022   2022m2    2022m1       5          3 |
  6. |      1   28feb2022   2022m2    2022m1       6          3 |
     +----------------------------------------------------------+
```